# Python: Handling multiple flags with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

When I execute python myscript.py -i -i myfile.txt
The output should be:

```
 info from file

 info from file
```

So everytime it comes across a flag a peice of code is executed even if it is outputting the same data.

At the moment it just prints:

info from file

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', help="info", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+')
results = parser.parse_args()

if results.i:
    print("info from file")
```

Comment: 'store_true' just sets  `results.i` once.  `action='count'` records the number of '-i'.  It is often used to set 'verbosity'.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action has an example.

Answer (score 0):

I mean I guess you could do something like this (that's if I'm understanding your question correctly):

```
import sys
import argparse


def parse_i(args, to_parse):
    times_counted = 0
    for arg in args:
        if arg == to_parse:
            times_counted += 1
    return times_counted

if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', help="info", action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+')
    results = parser.parse_args()

    for _ in range(0, parse_i(sys.argv, "-i")):
        if results.i:
            print("info from file")
```

An example would be:

```
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/zeus-scanner# python file.py file -i 
info from file
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/zeus-scanner# python file.py file -i -i
info from file
info from file
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/zeus-scanner# python file.py file -i -i -i
info from file
info from file
info from file
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/zeus-scanner# python file.py file -i -i -i -i
info from file
info from file
info from file
info from file
root@baal-Aspire-5733Z:~/bin/python/zeus-scanner#
```

Comment: If using `sys.argv` like this, just skip the use of `argparse`.  Get the file name directly from `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'count' action rather than 'store_true':

```
In [373]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [374]: parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='+');
In [375]: parser.add_argument('-i', action='count');
In [376]: args = parser.parse_args('-i -i myfile.txt'.split())

In [377]: print(args)
Namespace(filename=['myfile.txt'], i=2)

In [378]: for i in range(args.i): print(args.filename)
['myfile.txt']
['myfile.txt']
```

Without `-i`:

```
In [379]: args = parser.parse_args('myfile.txt'.split())
In [380]: print(args)
Namespace(filename=['myfile.txt'], i=None)
```

With the default `None`, you'd need catch the `None` case with:

```
if args.i:
    # do the rest
```

Setting the default to 0 would simplify that testing:

```
parser.add_argument('-i', action='count', default=0);
```